# AngularJS: Handling Model data injection in Controller

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, publish-subscribe

I have two controllers, to add Item and to delete Item, and a Model to show all items.
This model is injected into the controller ( on working on same template).

Whenever an item is added, I broadcast a message, which is listened by Model and it reloads the data from server.

Code:

```
ItemModule.factory('ItemListModal', function ($resource, $rootScope){
  var allItem = $resource('item/page/:pageId.json', {'pageId': pageId });
  var items = allItem.query();
  $rootScope.$on('ItemAdded',function(){
         items = allItem.query();
  });
  return items;
});

//Item is another Model, used to send data on server.
function CreateItemCtrl($scope, $rootScope, Item) {
    $scope.save = function() {
    Item.save($scope.item, function(data) {
                      $scope.result = data;
                      $rootScope.$broadcast('ItemAdded');
                    }, function(data) { 
                      $scope.result = data.data;
      });
    }
}

function ListItemCtrl($scope, ItemListModal) {
    $scope.allItems = ItemListModal;
}
```

Issue: Now since the dependency on ListItemCtrl is already resolved when template was first loaded, on adding Item it only changes the Model, but this is not re-injected into the ListItemCtrl. And due to this, the list on template do not change.

Is there any way to tell AngularJS to re-resolve the controller's dependency?

I really don't want to listen for event in Controllers and re-query data there, as there are other controllers which also needs same data from server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another level of indirection on what you return from your service.

```
ItemModule.factory('ItemListModal', function ($resource, $rootScope){
  var allItem = $resource('item/page/:pageId.json', {'pageId': pageId });
  var data = {items:allItem.query()};
  $rootScope.$on('ItemAdded',function(){
         data.items = allItem.query();
  });
  return data;
});


function ListItemCtrl($scope, ItemListModal) {
    $scope.allItems = ItemListModal;
    // use as $scope.allItems.items wherever you need it.  It will update when changes occur.
}
```

But it might be better to have a canonical representation of the item list on the client, and work to keep that current when you add things (just saving it to the server quietly).

Comment: It worked, Thanks. Could you please explain, why it worked this way by adding another indirection?

Comment: Every time you call allItem.query() it returns a reference to a different object.   If you put the first object in your scope, the second object doesn't automatically replace it.  If you instead return an object which points at the first object, then later modify that object to point at the second object, then your container object will always be up to date.  I hope that helps, it sounds confusing now that I reread it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that while item is getting updated (have you tried console.log in the $on?) it's not an object and so hasn't been passed by reference. If you switch around your service to this:

```
ItemModule.factory('ItemListModal', function ($resource, $rootScope){
    var ItemListModalScope = this;
    var allItem = $resource('item/page/:pageId.json', {'pageId': pageId });
    ItemListModalScope.items = allItem.query();
    $rootScope.$on('ItemAdded',function(){
        ItemListModalScope.items = allItem.query();
    });
    return ItemListModalScope;
});
```

And then wherever you use your allItems in your dome, you would do

```
{{ allItems.items }}
```

Comment: what is {{allItems.list}}, we never saved anything in 'list'. Do you mean {{allItems.items}}? If so, that is not working. I did console.log in $on, data comes from server. Issue is its not re-injected into ListItemCtrl. Any thought?